# Use REST API in Ruby on Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I plan to develop a Ruby on Rails application which uses instead of database an application (in this case VMware vCenter Orchestrator). To be honest, Orchestrator in turn uses database to store and retrieve data, but this should be masked from portal application. So I have following code in controller:

```
class WorkflowsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /workflows
  # GET /workflows.json
  def index
    @workflows = Workflow.list

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @workflows }
    end
 end
```

and I modified the module models\workflow.rb to implement list method:

```
class Workflow

  def initialize ( id, name, url )
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @url = url
 end

 def  list ()
   ret = Array.new
   wf = Hash.new
   vco = Vco.new
   vco.getAll.each do |link|
     link['attributes'].each do |attr|
       wf[ attr['name'] ] = attr[ 'value' ]
     end
     ret.push( self.new( wf[ 'id' ], wf[ 'name' ], wf[ 'itemHref' ]  ) )
   end
   return   ret
 end
```

Class Vco in turn is implemented in models\vco.rb

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to access the page - http://ruby.on.rails:3000/workflows

I'm getting the error message

undefined method `list' for Workflow:Class

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: replace `def list` with `def self.list`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Should I generally use self.MethodName ?

Comment: whenever you're calling a class method, yes

Comment: Sorry still getting error, now it is "undefined method `getAll' for #<Vco:0x2bc7160>". As mentioned above class Vco is defined in models\vco.rb, and according to your advice I used there "def self.getAll"

Comment: Hmmm, looks like there I shouldn't use self.MethodName, will check it

Comment: please take a look at http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/ to understand it better.